# Word Control in VS 2005

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2005

I am using VS 2005.

I want to drag-and-drop a Word Document 2003/2007 control  in my form by .NET Framework. Like we do for PDF in the following screenshot. If you see the highlighted text, it is Adobe PDF Reader. I can show the PDF documents in this control in my form.

Similarly can I do for Word?

[image: PDF]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may get you started:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/WordInDotnet.aspx

Comment: I underwent this article. I made some changes. Can I save the document using this control ?

Comment: Look at the sample app Save button code: 
    objWinWordControl.document.Save();

Comment: Can you provide any link for inbuilt ocx under .net framework